# Jquery Nav disappears when clicked on

Tags: jquery, css, nav

Working on some jquery nav tabs,

The problem

1) when click on a tab the main navigation disappears !
Can anyone see why???

http://jsfiddle.net/w8e8y/

```
/*  TABS
===================================================================*/

$(".profile-tabs a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    idTab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".profile-tabs .active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(idTab).siblings().stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(idTab).fadeIn(300);
        }, 300)
    })
    // $(idTab).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are hiding all its siblings including the `uls`. Instead use an [attribute endswith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector or use a common `classname` for the content divs, Change it to :

```
   $(idTab).siblings('div[id$=-tab]').stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(idTab).fadeIn(300);
        }, 300)
    });
```

from

```
$(idTab).siblings().stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(idTab).fadeIn(300);
        }, 300)
    })
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VsU9/)**

Comment: thanks dude , appreciate it. how did you learn jquery? i find it difficult

Comment: @PaulDesigner You are welcome. No worries, you will get there... :) learing css selectors will help in using selectors in jquery and for the individual function you can refer online... :)

Comment: Thannks @PSL appreciate it